# septic system smells in basement bathroom

Tags: bathroom

have an existing bathroom in basement - we have a septic system.  Bathroom has smells from the system- no vent.  How do we vent without tearing up the walls?

Comment: Did this just start, or has it always smelled?

Comment: Sometimes you just have to tear open walls.

Comment: One house I built had all working plumbing, all traps were in, but it was a huge house and only 2 people living in it. The smell they experienced came from drains in showers and sinks they did not use and the p traps dried out where the fumes passed on through. They now at least turn on the water in those places periodically to keep water in the trap.

Answer (score 1):

Drywall is the enemy! and in your case, so is concrete.